# NativeScript - Restart app using iBeacon, AppDelegate must implement window property

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nativescript, ibeacon

i'm working on a NativeScript application that communicates with a BLE device, i need to use beacons to restart the application.

I created a nativescript plugin to use a custom BLE SDK implemented in native code (swift), the startMonitoring(region) method is used in the SDK, it works fine as long as the application is foreground/background, but if the application is closed i get this error:

"The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file."

I tried to add a custom AppDelegate in NativeScript with a window property, but nothing has changed, this is my CustomAppDelegate:

```
export class CustomAppDelegate extends UIResponder implements UIApplicationDelegate {
    public static ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];
    window:UIWindow;

    applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(application: UIApplication, launchOptions: NSDictionary<string, any>): boolean {
        console.log("applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions: " + launchOptions)

        return true;
    }

    applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication): void {
        console.log("applicationDidBecomeActive: " + application)
    }
}

if (platform.isIOS) {
    ios.delegate = CustomAppDelegate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a getter,

```
export class CustomAppDelegate extends UIResponder implements UIApplicationDelegate {
    ....

    get window() {
       return undefined;
    }
}
```